# How to reboot mac remotely using Jenkins

Tags: macos, jenkins, remote-access, expect

I need to reboot my mac remotely using Jenkins job.
For example I have next ios user:

> **login** - user,
>   **pass** - 123

I try to execute next command:

```
expect -c 'spawn sudo shutdown -r now ; expect Password:;send 123\n;interact'
```

it works on the mac and it reboots, but does not work in Jenkins(job run but rebooting doesn't).

Comment: When you did your test, you was connected with the jenkins user? Maybe this user doesn't have the sudo permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

work out which user the mac runs commands from jenkins as (for example jenkinsuser)

use visudo to add this to the sudoers file on the remote mac

```
jenkinsuser             ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

Then the command "sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now" should work